# Jigsaw Maven JavaFX Project - How to export?

Tags: maven, javafx, java-platform-module-system

I am developing a JavaFX application in a single maven module using Java modules (Jigsaw). My app runs and I don't have errors or warnings in Eclipse. Now I want to export a running jar.

I tried this:
mvn clean install javafx:jlink

And got this error message:
"automatic module cannot be used with jlink: org.slf4j from file:///home/user1/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar"

This is how my module-info.class looks like:

```
    //needed exports
    exports myapp to javafx.graphics;
    exports myapp.gui to javafx.fxml;
    exports myapp.model to javafx.fxml;
    opens myapp.gui to javafx.fxml;

    // javafx
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    requires transitive javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;

    // log4j
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j;
    requires junit;
    requires org.slf4j;
```

Any idea on how to export a runnable jar?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple. Automatic modules are just not supported by jlink. Have a look here to see how this can be circumvented: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: I did another aproach now, which solved my problem. My app was already using SLF4J, the logging worked. But its seems there was one maven dependency missing that supports Jigsaw for SLF4J.                                                                           <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.30</version>
  </dependency>                                                                                                               What do you think about this way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok jlink still had trouble with it.

This is the solution
https://leward.eu/2020/01/20/java-module-slf4j-jlink-javafx.html

Using a newer slf4j (alpha 2.x).

It simply sums up to every module needing to be a jigsaw module project...

Comment: Your conclusion is only true if, for whatever reason, you insist on using jlink the way you do it. If you'd followed they way I have described above, then none of your modules would have to be jigsaw modules.

Comment: @mipa i am very strict in using third party software. And maybe JPackageScriptFX is good. I dont know. But there must be a standard way to use Maven, JavaFX, JigSaw with only dependencies to https://openjfx.io/ (besides junit und slf4j which is quite standard). But honestly, I am not fully understanding everything yet. I doing try and error. Right now i have a jar, but its not yet runnable. "no main manifest attribute".